# Could not read status of path (which was just about to install): Input/output error

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude, dpkg, devuan

I am using Debian bullseye without systemd (devuan) and today I wanted to upgrade my packages. So I typed

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

It didn't work because I got the following error (note that this error was translated from Swedish language os to English using google-translate):

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.10.0-25-amd64_5.10.191-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
  could not read status of "./boot/System.map-5.10.0-25-amd64" (which was just about to install): Input/output error
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (The pipe was broken)
W: Last kernel image has been removed, so removing the default symlinks
An error occurred while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.10.0-25-amd64_5.10.191-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I tried to use `apt --fix-broken install`, it still doesn't work.

I tried to search google, but I didn't quite find anything quite like this problem. What does it mean and how will I debug and fix it?

---

EDIT:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Devuan GNU/Linux 4.0 chimaera amd64 - desktop 20211012]/ chimaera contrib main non-free

deb http://deb.devuan.org/merged chimaera main
deb-src http://deb.devuan.org/merged chimaera main

deb http://pkgmaster.devuan.org/merged chimaera-security main
deb-src http://pkgmaster.devuan.org/merged chimaera-security main

# chimaera-updates, to get updates before a point release is made;
# see https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_updates_and_backports
deb http://deb.devuan.org/merged chimaera-updates main
deb-src http://deb.devuan.org/merged chimaera-updates main
```

EDIT 2:
I solved my problem. The issue was that I have the /boot directory on a removable USB-drive that I remove after I have booted. When I tried to repeat the process with the USB-drive plugged in, it all worked.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148239/discussion-on-question-by-mikke-mus-could-not-read-status-of-path-which-was-jus); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved the problem! Please consider writing an answer post and describe your solution there instead of your question post. The Q&A format of this site demands to separate solutions from problems. Otherwise, others may overlook a valuable solution. Also, consider updating your question with any relevant details, but don't change your question.

Comment: Consider also accepting your own answer, so it is clear marked as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved my problem after months. It was suggested in the comments to put the solution into an answer. The issue was that I have the /boot-directory on a removable USB-drive that I unplug after I have booted. When I tried to repeat the process with the USB-drive plugged in, it all worked. So this is an example of where the input/output-error came as a result of a hardware issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could prepend `LC_ALL=C` before your commands to set the locale to C and so display the output in English. The actual error in English would be something like this:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.10.0-25-amd64_5.10.191-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
  unable to stat './boot/System.map-5.10.0-25-amd64' (which I was about to install): Input/output error
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
W: Last kernel image has been removed, so removing the default symlinks
Errors were encountered while processing:
  /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.10.0-25-amd64_5.10.191-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This means that `apt` could not read from the `deb` archive of the downloaded package located at `/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.10.0-25-amd64_5.10.191-1_amd64.deb`, in particular the file `System.map-5.10.0-25-amd64` from the `boot` directory. It could be due to the archive of the package `linux-image-5.10.0-25-amd64` written to disk or downloaded incorrectly when fetched from the repository. The I/O error here would be due to the inability of the output of the unpacking subprocess to be passed as input for further processing.

I would try cleaning the whole `apt` cache, including the downloaded archive, then proceed with upgrading once again.

```
$ sudo apt clean
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

---

The default apt sources list for Devuan Chimaera 4.0, [which is based on Debian Bullseye 11.1 and has Linux kernel 5.10](https://www.devuan.org/os/announce/chimaera-release-announce-2021-10-14), is:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Devuan GNU/Linux 4.0 chimaera amd64 - netinstall 20211012]/ chimaera contrib main non-free

#deb cdrom:[Devuan GNU/Linux 4.0 chimaera amd64 - netinstall 20211012]/ chimaera contrib main non-free

deb http://deb.devuan.org/merged chimaera main
deb-src http://deb.devuan.org/merged chimaera main

deb http://pkgmaster.devuan.org/merged chimaera-security main contrib non-free
deb-src http://pkgmaster.devuan.org/merged chimaera-security main contrib non-free

# chimaera-updates, to get updates before a point release is made;
# see https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_updates_and_backports
deb http://deb.devuan.org/merged chimaera-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.devuan.org/merged chimaera-updates main contrib non-free

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

Every line that is commented out with `#` can be skipped because it is just a comment that is not used. You might want to add `contrib non-free` after `main` if you are using software from those repositories, for example non-free Wi-Fi firmware which is typical for a laptop. The lines starting with `deb-src` are for sources and are not used in the ordinary installation and upgrade of packages.

Additional sources entries might be hiding in the `sources.list.d` directory, which is empty by default:

```
$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
$
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. When I executed the apt clean + update + upgrade commands, it seemed nothing changed apart from that apt downloaded the archive again. After that, the errors were the same.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a few things, disk error itself could be one, try a fsck and see if it helps. `sudo fsck -f /dev/{device}`

Second I would try to clean apt cache entirely entirely "sudo apt clean"

Then try to reconfigure/reinstall

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`
and
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall {affected package}`

Past that, this could become some brain surgery and end up no being worth it of the system can simply be nuked/reloaded.